missing modulus in derivative of cosech inverse
I want to derive the formula for $\frac{d}{dx}cosech^{-1}x$.
Here are the steps:
$$
\begin{align*}
y = cosech^{-1}(x) &&&&..(1)\\
cosech(y) = x &&&&..(2)\\
\frac{d}{dx}cosech(y) = \frac{d}{dx}x &&&&..(3)\\
-cosech(y) * coth(y) \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 &&&&..(4)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{cosech(y)*coth(y)} &&&&..(5)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{cosech(y)*\sqrt{cosech^2(y) + 1}} &&&&..(6)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{cosech(cosech^{-1}(x))*\sqrt{cosech^2(cosech^{-1}(x)) + 1}} &&&&..(7)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} &&&&..(8)
\end{align*}
$$
But the formula is $$\frac{d}{dx}cosech^{-1}x = -\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Taking a slightly different route yields the correct solution.
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{sinh^2(y)}{cosh(y)}  &&&&..(6)\\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{sinh^2(y)}{\sqrt{1 + sinh^2(y)}}  &&&&..(7)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{sinh^2(cosech^{-1}(x))}{\sqrt{1 + sinh^2(cosech^{-1}(x))}}  &&&&..(8)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{sinh^2(sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}))}{\sqrt{1 + sinh^2(sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}))}}  &&&&..(9)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}}  &&&&..(10)\\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{|x|}{x^2\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}  &&&&..(11)\\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}  &&&&..(12)
\end{align*}
$$
What am I missing here?
Apologies if this question has been asked before or if the answer is trivial.

When you converted $\coth y$ into $\sqrt{1+\operatorname{cosech}^2(y)}$ you forgot that $\coth$ can be negative in the range of $\operatorname{cosech}$, but because $\coth$ and $\operatorname{cosech}$ have the same sign you have to add the absolute value.
Let's dig into it. You've already proved that
\begin{align}
y=\operatorname{cosech}^{-1}(x)\:&\Longrightarrow\:\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{\operatorname{cosech}(y)\coth(y)}
\end{align}
Now suppose that $x>0$. Observe that, since $x>0$, $y=\operatorname{cosech}^{-1}(x)>0$, so $\coth(y)>0$ and, consequently, $\coth(y)=+\sqrt{1+\operatorname{cosech}^2(y)}$. Exactly as you've done this implies that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}},\qquad x>0$$
While if $x<0$ the value of $y=\operatorname{cosech}^{-1}(x)<0$ is negative, so $\coth(y)<0$ and, consequently, $\coth(y)=-\sqrt{1+\operatorname{cosech}^2(y)}$. At this point:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=-\frac{1}{\operatorname{cosech}(y)\coth(y)}
\\&=-\frac{1}{-\operatorname{cosech}(y)\sqrt{1+\operatorname{cosech}^2(y)}}
\\&=-\frac{1}{-\operatorname{cosech}(\operatorname{cosech}^{-1}(x))\sqrt{1+\operatorname{cosech}^2(\operatorname{cosech}^{-1}(x))}}
\\&=-\frac{1}{(-x)\sqrt{1+x^2}},\qquad x<0
\end{align}
This gives us:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}},\quad\qquad x>0\\
-\frac{1}{(-x)\sqrt{1+x^2}},\qquad x<0
\end{cases}$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{1+x^2}},\qquad x\neq 0$$
